# Data not showing when retrieved from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a drop down menu where it display Id; retrieved from RSVP table in database and 4 labels to show date,day, time and total. When user selects 4(Id), the labels should display all data that belongs to Id 4. But my code doesn't work. Here is my code and I hope you can help me. Many thanks.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Date,Day,Time,Total FROM RSVP WHERE Id = @dummy",conn);

      cmd.Parameters.Add("@dummy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text;

            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows == false)
            {
                throw new Exception();   
            }
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                Label1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                Label2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                Label3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                Label4.Text = dr[3].ToString();
             }

 }
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Are you sure all those fields have values, maybe you have a null lurking in one of those ! !

Comment: on which line u are getting error

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@dummy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text; This line

Comment: Well do you have anything set as selected explicitly ? highly unlikely for the `SelectedItem` to have a relevant value, probably you need that code in the selectedindex changed event of the dropdown

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the error on this line

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dummy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text;
```

then probably nothing has been selected in the drop down list and that is why you are getting the error.

you may add a check before the line to see if the SelectedItem is null.

```
if(DropDownList5.SelectedItem != null)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@dummy", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Comment: That is because you are not selecting any item in the drop down list now, and because of the check that parameter @dummy is not getting added to the parameter list. You need to make sure that you are selecting something from the drop down. The idea was to tell you about the error, you need to resolve the original problem which is **not anything getting selected in the dropdownlist**

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString);
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Date, Day, Time, Total FROM RSVP WHERE Id = @dummy", conn);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dummy", DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Text);

         conn.open();
         var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         if (dr.HasRows == false)
           throw new Exception("No data found!");   
         if (dr.Read())
         {
            Label1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            Label2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            Label3.Text = dr[2].ToString();
            Label4.Text = dr[3].ToString();
         }
         conn.close();
     }
```